# Proving an explicit formula through strong induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, induction

A sequence is defined as $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 2$ when $a_n = 2a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2$.  Find and prove an explicit formula for $a_n$

To prove that $a_0 = 1$, when $n \ge 2$

Then plugging in $2$ into $a_n$, we get:

$a_0 = 2a_{2-2}+a_{2-1} = 2a_0 + a_1 = 2(1)+2 = 4$ which does not hold when $a_0=1$ unless I have approached this in the wrong way, please let me know?

I am slightly confused on how to approach this

Comment: What on earth does "prove that $a_0=1$, when $n≥2$" mean? You're given $a_0=1$ full stop. And if you plug $n=2$ into the formula the LHS is $a_2$ not $a_0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation

Comment: Reread what you have written , it is confusing. Looks like the first problem you have is to actually undergo the question, do not try to solve it , just explain the problem to yourself first .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

- $a_0=1$;
- $a_1=2$;
- $a_2=2a_0+a_1=4$;
- $a_3=2a_1+a_2=8$;
- $a_4=2a_2+a_3=16$

and so on… This suggests that $(\forall n\in\Bbb Z_+):a_n=2^n$. Is it true? Yes. It is true if $n\in\{0,1\}$. Now, take $n>1$ and suppose that $a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}$ and that $a_{n-2}=2^{n-2}$. Then\begin{align}a_n&=2a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}\\&=2\times2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}\\&=2^n.\end{align}

Comment: This plus the previous answer combined blew my mind! I was confusing with where to begin based on a psychological induction of induction. However, this has cemented some patterns I had thought were not True, to now be True! AMAZING! Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n = 2a_{n−2}+a_{n−1}$

$a_0, a_1$ are already given. You are wrong when you write $a_{\color{red} 0} = 2 a_{\color{red}{2 - 2}} + a_{\color{red}{2 - 1}}$. Because if $n = 0$ then $n-2$ and $n-1$ are $-2$ and $-1$ respectively. This is essentially why the first two values are given and the equation is to get $a_n$ for $n \geq 2$.

If you worked out a few more values, you would have realized:

\begin{align*}
a_0 &= 1,\\ a_1 &= 2, \\a_2 &= 2 + 2 \times 1 = 4 \\ a_3 &= 4 + 2 \times 2 = 8
\end{align*}

which are essentially the exponents of $2$.

Can you now prove that $a_n = 2^n$?

Hint: Use Induction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the following solution :

Lets say that the value of $a_n=t^2$ ,then $a_{n-1}=t$ , $a_{n-2}=1$. Hence  ,the equation turned out to be $$t^2 = t +2 \rightarrow t^2 -t -2 = (t-2)(t+1)$$.

Hence , $t= 2 , -1$. Then , $$a_n= \alpha_12^n + \alpha_2(-1)^n$$

If $a_0=1$ , then $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 =1$

If $a_1=2$ , then $2\alpha_1 - \alpha_2 =2$

By solving this linear equation , we see that $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_2=0$

Hence ; $a_n=1 \times 2^n + 0 \times (-1)^n = 2^n$